# Eevee flickering issue with reflective materials

Tags: eevee-render-engine

Is there a way to get rid of the flickering happening when using reflective materials in Eevee?

I tried a bunch of things, none of them worked.

I changed the camera clip start to 1 m (I read somewhere that would help).
I also tried denoising the beauty, and the glossy pass, to no avail.

Here's an example of the issue:

[image]

Any hints?

Comment: Use more samples.

Comment: I increased the samples, it's not affecting the result. In the example I posted, I'm using 128 samples for the final render.

Comment: My guess is that you're using a bump or normal map that is way too strong.  But there's no way to confirm that without a file.

Comment: Thanks, @Nathan


The normal maps are not too strong.
The issue is actually showing up even with materials without bump/normal maps, and it seems to be related to the roughness when it's too low.


Here's an example with a 0.07 roughness
https://ibb.co/JsbNrCV


And this is with a 0.4 roughness
https://ibb.co/JrSK7mN


I'll try a render with these settings to see if that helps.
I can't post the file directly as it contains some commercial maps, but I'll see if I can simplify the project, and post a sample

Comment: Ok.  If you can link a file that reproduces the issue, I'll look.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look, Nathan

Here's an example:
https://file.io/Hp2iBFjJtuNq

I stripped the file from many elements, and just left a cable, and the walls. Once you render it, you'll notice how the reflection on these materials are flickering from frame to frame.

Here's a preview of the clip:
https://file.io/k60ci23bXPEN

Comment: Your level of detail is too much for your resolution, leading to sampling errors: the angle between the lights and the faces changes dramatically in the span of a single frame.  Render at a higher framerate or increase the steps for your motion blur.  Consider moving your lights further from your meshes to create slower changing specular.  Consider using lower poly meshes with textural details (incl normal maps) so that you can take advantage of texture filtering.

Comment: Thank you, Nathan,
I'll re-work the scene, starting with the higher frame rate.
I didn't fully test it yet, but apparently, I might have similar problems even when I switch to cycles. I imported the scene into C4D, and did a test with Redshift, where things seem to hold up quite well. I wonder if there's some intrinsic limitation in Blender with this type of scenario.